# MVC3 Editor For Double showing scientific notation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a property of my model that is of type double.  One of my items has a value of 0.000028, but when my edit view is rendered, the editor for this value shows as 2.8e-005.

Aside from this being confusing to my users, it also fails my regular expression validation of

```
    [Display(Name = "Neck Dimension")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Neck Dimension must be a Number")]
    [Range(0, 9999.99, ErrorMessage = "Value must be between 0 - 9,999.99")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Neck Dimension is required.")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:F20}")]
    public double? NeckDimension { get; set; }
```

How do I get this field to display? I've got this bit of code (shown below) that will render a decimal like I want, but I'm not sure where to implement it.

```
 var dbltest = 0.000028D;
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F20}", dbltest).TrimEnd('0'));
```

I use the property NeckDimension in two places, and edit view and a display view. Here is how each are being rendered.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NeckDimension, new { style = "width:75px;" })

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NeckHDimension)
```

**UPDATE**
Apparently the DisplayFormat won't work with TextBoxFor.  I attempted to change my @Html.TextBoxFor to an Html.EditorFor and giving it a class but it failed with the following exception.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Double', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'
```

This old code still works:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NeckDimension, new { style = "width:75px;" })
```

This code gave the exception:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NeckDimension, new {@class = "formatteddecimal"})
```

It looks like my options are fix this with javascript or fix it with an editor template, but I don't have the time to research and learn the 2nd option at this point.

**SOLUTION:**

I created an editor template for double? as follows.

```
@model double?
@{
    var ti = ViewData.TemplateInfo;
    var displayValue = string.Empty;
    if (Model.HasValue) { 
        displayValue = String.Format("{0:F20}", @Model.Value).TrimEnd('0');
    }
    <input id="@ti.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)" name="@ti.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)" type="text" value="@displayValue" />
}
```

Comment: I like @Darin Dimitrov's approach of using the DisplayFormat decorator, but it doesn't work in my case.  I'm not sure if one of the other decorators is throwing this off, but I still need a solution that works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could decorate the property on your view model with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:F20}")]
public double Foo { get; set; }
```

and now in your strongly typed views simply:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo)
```

or if it is for editing:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
```

Another possibility if you wanted to apply this format for all doubles in your application or per controller is to write a [custom display/editor template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html).

Comment: I've added the DisplayFormat as per your example but I'm still getting the scientific notation. Any thoughts? I've added my property in the question with all decorators.

Comment: I should add that the value 0.000028 using the format of "0:F20" is going to return 0.00002800000000000000, which is not desirable either. That's why my code in my example uses the .TrimEnd('0').

Comment: @JeffReddy, I am not sure I understand what the problem is. If you want 6 numbers after the decimal separator why don't you use the `{0:F6}` format?

Comment: LOL. Could be that I didn't understand the format, 0:F6. Although I won't know the decimal value or the number of places I'll need. I just don't want the zeros. A value like .000000028, would require 0:F8, so 0:F6 wouldn't work.

Comment: @Jeff, assuming you want to work with a limited precision, for example 6 numbers after the decimal point you could use the `{0:0.######}` format. If not, writing a custom editor/display template might be the way to go where you would manually strip trailing zeros in order to achieve your custom format that is not supported by any built-in qualifier.

Comment: thanks for the help with the formatting info While that's good stuff to know, I still have the issue with the formatting not being applied. My editorfor and displayfor are still rendering "2.8e-005", event with the  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0.######}")] applied.

Comment: @JeffReddy, if the DisplayFormat attribute is ignored this means that you are not using the `Html.EditorFor` or `Html.DisplayFor` helpers in your view as shown in my answer. You are probably using `Html.TextBoxFor` which ignores this attribute.

Comment: I am using the TextBoxFor because I needed to apply HTML attributes to the rendered input control.  The default textbox created with EditorFor has a width that cut's off most of my value). So each solution I use has other adverse affects.

Comment: @JeffReddy, there are many possibilities to solve this problem. One possibility is to write a custom metadata provider and custom editor templates (http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx). Another possibility (the one I use in my projects) simply consists in customizing the default editor templates for the standard types and pass additional html attributes to be applied using the second argument of the editorfor helper: `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo, new { @class = "foo" })`.

Comment: I tried your second approach that you say you use in your projects. It fails when it tries to render. Expects a double and is supplied a string exception.  I created a Editor Template for a double, got my formatting to work, but lost all validation, model binding and everything good that I had.  I accepted your answer and upvoted it as well.  I'm giving up on this for now.